# Ball dropping animation not working (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This code is supposed to drop a ball from the top of the screen to the bottom. And once it touches the bottom of the screen, it should appear back to the top of the screen. It doesn't relocate to the top and it stops moving. I want it to be a continuous loop that resets the ball.y position every time it touches the bottom.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 20)
    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Futura")
    let movingObjects = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        self.physicsBody = sceneBody

        //Ball Transition
        let ballTransition = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(1)])
        ball.runAction(ballTransition)

        //Ball function
        ball.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()

        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
        ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        //Ball Movement
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: CGFloat(self.frame.size.height*1))

        ballMovement()

        movingObjects.addChild(ball)

        self.addChild(label)
    }

    func ballMovement() {
        let moveBall = SKAction.moveToY(self.frame.size.height*0, duration: 3)
        let removeBall = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveBall, removeBall])
        ball.runAction(moveAndRemove)

        //Label Sprite
        label.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        label.fontColor = SKColor.redColor()
        label.fontSize = 30
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        label.text = "\(ball.position.y)"

        if ball.position.y < 26 {
            ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: CGFloat(self.frame.size.height*1))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part is not working? The dropping or the relocation?

Comment: neither part it just crashes, it was working fine before. @TheValyreanGroup

Comment: Before what?  What is the crash error?

Comment: Shouldn't you add `movingObjects` to the scene?

Comment: lots of things could be going wrong,  my guess is,  your ball is skipping larger than 26 pixels,  and is being removed before you relocate, or is taking more than 3 seconds, and is being removed

Comment: What is the point of multiplying swith zero? self.frame.size.height*0 ? ;)

Comment: So it brings the ball to the bottom @Whirlwind

Comment: Multiplying with zero is always equal to zero. Passing just 0 is enough.

Answer (score 1):

removing the ball from its parent within the action and still acting on it elsewhere is going to become very fragile as your program gets more complex.   Why not just do it all with the actions and let sprite kit worry about it ?

```
 let moveBall = SKAction.moveToY(0, duration: 3)
 let goBackUp = SKAction.moveToY(self.frame.size.height, duration:0)
 let keepFalling = SKAction.sequence([moveBall, goBackUp])
 ball.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(keepFalling))
```